# Gstreamer video stream error and breaks /dev/video source

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, v4l2

The pipeline is what I am using with a Logitech C920 camera to stream H264 video, as follows:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-h264,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! h264parse ! tee name=t ! queue ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=1234
```

(the tee is for splitting for saving the stream later)

This pipeline works. However, after some time, the pipeline would crash:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
libv4l2: error dequeuing buf: No such device
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2865): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming task paused, reason error (-5)
EOS on shutdown enabled -- waiting for EOS after Error
Waiting for EOS...
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
EOS received - stopping pipeline...
Execution ended after 0:12:06.806371505
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
libv4l2: error turning off stream: No such device
libv4l2: error turning off stream: No such device
libv4l2: error turning off stream: No such device
libv4l2: error querying buffer 0: No such device
libv4l2: error turning off stream: No such device
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

This would normally be okay, but by crashing this way, the video object (/dev/video1) is destroyed and disappears. It shows up again once I unplug and replug the camera in. I am controlling this remotely, so I cannot go and reset the camera this way.

How did this happen? And is there any way to resolve this issue? Some way of rebuilding the /dev/video* object?

Edit1: After messing around some more with the pipeline, this apparently works:

gst-launch-1.0 -v -e v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-h264,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 !  tee name=t ! queue ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=1234

I just moved the h264parse to after the tee. Still no idea why this works, or what the original issue was.